# JMeter: comparing ASCII character

Tags: compare, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

When I run Jmeter, a test case fails because it compares unwanted ASCII character

following is the result:

```
Data 'Â£107.29K' is missing;
Data 'Â£131.72K' is missing;
Data 'Â£67.05K' is missing;
Data 'Â£93.84K' is missing;
Data '£107.29K' is new;
Data '£131.72K' is new;
Data '£67.05K' is new;
Data '£93.84K' is new;
```

When I check the responses, there is no such character in expected response. Not any difference is shown in comparing the responses.

How can I skip this comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Try coverting your string to utf-8

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = original.getBytes("UTF8");
String roundTrip = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF8");
```

You can refer this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html

Comment: it just picks up expected response from a csv file that has invisible Â character. I showed all the symbols in notepad++, but couldn't catch any.

Comment: try changing the encoding of ur csv file in notepad++ and try this piece of java code as well. It might help. I have faced similar scenario with Japanese characters.